# Git failing to update tag with fatal: tag 'v0.0.8' already exists

Tags: git

Git failing to update tag with fatal: tag 'v0.0.8' already exists

This is the output of my command. It's supposed to update from the latest tag v0.0.8 to v0.0.7.

```
 ./archive/tag_git_repo.sh
Updating v0.0.7 to v0.0.8
[feature/Jenkinsfile 76c4601] Updating v0.0.7 to v0.0.8
fatal: cannot describe '76c4601af575392eec851e4f86bb12f3e2f849b3'
Tagged with v0.0.8 (Ignoring fatal:cannot describe - this means commit is untagged)
fatal: tag 'v0.0.8' already exists
Everything up-to-date
```

This is the source code of the script:

```
$ cat archive/tag_git_repo.sh
#!/bin/bash

#fetch all tags!
git fetch --tags

#get highest tag number
VERSION=`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`

#replace . with space so can split into an array
VERSION_BITS=(${VERSION//./ })

#get number parts and increase last one by 1
VNUM1=${VERSION_BITS[0]}
VNUM2=${VERSION_BITS[1]}
VNUM3=${VERSION_BITS[2]}
VNUM3=$((VNUM3+1))

#create new tag
NEW_TAG="$VNUM1.$VNUM2.$VNUM3"

echo "Updating $VERSION to $NEW_TAG"
git commit --allow-empty -m "Updating $VERSION to $NEW_TAG"

#get current hash and see if it already has a tag
GIT_COMMIT=`git rev-parse HEAD`
NEEDS_TAG=`git describe --contains $GIT_COMMIT`

#only tag if no tag already (would be better if the git describe command above could have a silent option)
if [ -z "$NEEDS_TAG" ]; then
    echo "Tagged with $NEW_TAG (Ignoring fatal:cannot describe - this means commit is untagged) "
    git tag $NEW_TAG
    git push --tags
else
    echo "Already a tag on this commit"
fi
```

You can see I've fetched the latest tags and it shows v0.0.8, but still shows v0.0.7 as the current tag of the repository.

```
$ git fetch --tags
$ git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
v0.0.7

$ git tag
v0.0.1
v0.0.2
v0.0.3
v0.0.4
v0.0.5
v0.0.6
v0.0.7
v0.0.8
$ git describe --tags
v0.0.7-3-g76c4601
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "_... update from the latest tag v0.0.8 to v0.0.7_" - you mean the other way round, right?

Comment: Oh, and as always with bash scripts, try adding `set -x` at the top. At least then you can see the exact commands run, and what each variable expanded to.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple tags can point to a single commit, but `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags` will only show one. Here's a demo.

```
$ git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
$ git tag foo
$ git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
foo
$ git tag bar
$ git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
bar
```

`git tag --points-at HEAD` will show all tags that point at the current commit.

```
$ git tag --points-at HEAD
foo
bar
```

As will `git log --decorate`

```
$ git log --decorate
commit 8ce1cfebecda68ba42226d0e6cd5dbebba76ae0b (HEAD -> master, tag: foo, tag: bar)
Author: Michael G. Schwern <schwern@pobox.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 4 09:39:34 2019 -0400

    first commit
```

This can be made the default in your `.gitconfig`, I recommend it.

```
[log]
        decorate = short
```

---

Your program will always tag because `-z` looks for a *null* string, it will still fire on `""`. You can use `-n` to look for a non-empty string and flip the logic.

```
NEEDS_TAG=`git describe --contains HEAD 2> /dev/null`

#only tag if no tag already (would be better if the git describe command above could have a silent option)
if [ -n "$NEEDS_TAG" ]; then
    echo "Already a tag on this commit"
else
    echo "New tag"
fi
```

Note using `2> /dev/null` to suppress error output.

But it's safer to instead completely ignore the output and check the exit value.

```
if `git describe --contains HEAD 2&>1 > /dev/null`; then
    echo "Already a tag on this commit"
else
    echo "New tag"
fi
```

Note it's redundant to find the commit hash for HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, `describe` without giving an explicit ref implies `HEAD`, so this means that tag `v0.0.8` exists in the repository, but is **not** reachable from `HEAD`.

It means that this last version tag is on a branch which has not been merged in the current branch yet.

Difficult to say a lot more without knowing about your tree structure, though.

Comment: This is too naive an analysis. Please refer to Schwern's answer.